# Integral models of p-adic representations

Tags: galois-representations

Let $G$ be a compact group and $K$ a finite extension of $Q_{p}$. If $\rho$ is a continuous representation of $G$ on a finite dimensional vector space over $K$, then it is well known that the semi-simplification of the reduction modulo $p$ of an integral model of $\rho$ only depends upon the isomorphism class over $K$ of $\rho$. 
Are there results or strategies that, given a $K$-representation $\rho$ as above, allow one to determine properties of all the possible integral models of $\rho$? For example: are there some conditions under which all the integral models of $\rho$ are semi-simple?
Where can I find references? Thanks!

Comment: Presumably over $K$ you mean "reduction modulo $\pi$" (for a uniformizer $\pi$ of $O_K$) rather than "reduction modulo $p$".  Anyway, "semi-simple" for modules $M$ over a ring $R$ admitting a "nontrivial" ideal theory is not a good notion: there are $R$-submodules $I M$ for an ideal $I$ of $R$ (preserved by all $R$-linear automorphisms of $M$). One exercise-level result is that if the reduction is irreducible then integral model is unique up to $K^{\times}$-scaling. Do you have specific "properties of all integral models" in mind? That would clarify the motivation.

Answer (score 4):

Let be focus on the two-dimensional case first.  Finding an integral model for $\rho$ is equivalent to choosing a lattice in $K^2$ that is invariant under $\rho(G)$.  So in this case you are asking for invariant points in the tree for $GL_2(K)$ under a compact subgroup
$\rho(G)$ of $GL_2(K)$.  There are various possibilities, and there is a nice paper of Bellaiche and Chenevier [Sous-groupes de $GL_2$ et arbres](http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~chenevier/articles/clos.pdf) discussing the possibilites.

When you say that you would like all integral models to be semi-simple, I'm not sure what you mean; but it say the represenation over $K$ is irreducible, then it will *never* happen that all the integral models have semi-simple reduction, if they are not themselves irreducible.  (This is a proposition of Ribet, and is easily seen in the tree-based picture.)

Just to illustrate how one argues: if two points in the tree are $\rho(G)$-invariant, then so will be all the points on the line segment joining them.  If $\rho(G)$ fixes an infinite half-line, this corresponds to an invariant one-dimensional space over $K$,
and so means that $\rho$ is reducible over $K$.  So if $\rho(G)$ is irreducible over $K$,
then the fixed set of $\rho(G)$ will be bounded and convex, which already imposes some
restrictions.  (One an prove Ribet's result by these sort of considerations: basically,
any extremal point of the fixed set of $\rho(G)$ will have non-simple reduction.)

Once you understand the $GL_2$ case you can imagine how to try and generalize things to
the $GL_n$ case, although the combinatorics becomes more complictated, and (as Bellaiche and Chenevier note) it is harder to say anything nice, because when $n > 2$, $GL_n$ is the full
automorphism group of the building.

Comment: Just a nitpick: the second paragraph should end, "... unless the reductions are themselves irreducible."

Comment: Dear Kevin, Thanks --- this is now fixed.

Comment: The Ribet-Bellaïche lemma is discussed by Mazur in his expository  talk *How can we construct abelian Galois extensions of basic number fields?* at the Ribet Conference. See http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/.


Comment: Dear Chandan, Thanks very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

For general representations, there are no such strategies and this is a very hard open problem, even for finite groups. Since your usual compact group will have various finite quotients, your problem is at least as hard. This rather older [survey](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183531476) by Reiner is a good place to start. Particularly pages 171-173 should be of interest to you.

As for semi-simplicity, you need to be clear about what you mean. In the integral world, the classical notion of semi-simplicity makes little sense, because your representations always have subrepresentations. E.g. if $\Gamma$ is an integral model, then $p\Gamma$ is a subrepresentation. But at least the Krull-Schmidt theorem holds in your setting, even though the indecomposable summands of an integral model might not sit in irreducible $K$-representations. In fact, if the semi-simplification of the reduction of $\rho$ contains two non-isomorphic irreducible components, then I believe that there is almost no hope for all integral models to only have indecomposable summands that sit in irreducible $K$-representations. (Clearly, if the reduction itself is not semi-simple then your integral models will be at least as badly behaved.)